# Deshabilitar días festivos en input date de HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5, calendar

Necesito dejar bloqueados algunos días como año nuevo o navidad, para que no sean seleccionables dentro del calendario.
Entonces tengo creada una lista con alguno de los días ejemplo:

```
var disableDates=['31-10-2020', '01-11-2020', '25-12-2020', '01-01-2021']
```

He visto soluciones con Datapicker de Javascript o Bootstrap, pero en mi caso debo seguir manteniendo mi formato actual.
Para que tenga referencias dejo un ejemplo de mi código actual :

```js
/*Restringo Fecha de anteriores a la de hoy */
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("fecha")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
/*Restringo Fecha de selección hasta 180 días después de la fecha actual */
var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split('T')[0]
    document.getElementsByName("fecha")[0].setAttribute('max', maxDate)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <div>
          Seleccione Fecha
          <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo lamento, pero que yo sepa no se pueden deshabilitar. Lo que se puede hacer es validar con JavaScript **después** de que el usuario haya seleccionado una fecha, y reaccionar acorde a eso.

Comment: o con un plugin ya sea de jquery o algún otro que hay disponibles. y editar los estilos para que se vea similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo `max` y `min` son atributos admitidos en `<input type="date" />`.
Sin embargo puedes agregar un poco de javascript para lograr lo que desées.

```js
const disableDates= ['2020-10-31', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-25', '2021-01-01']

const validate = dateString => {
  const date = new Date(dateString).toJSON().slice(0,10);
  console.log(date);
  if (disableDates.indexOf(date) > -1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.querySelector('input').onchange = evt => {
  if (!validate(evt.target.value)) {
    evt.target.value = '';
    const error = document.getElementById("error");
    error.innerHTML = "Esta fecha no es válida";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date"/>
<p id="error"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo lamento, **no se puede** excluir fechas de un input type date más allá de configurar `min` y `max`.

Lo que se puede es utilizar una validación personalizada, con [setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity).

```js
/*Restringo Fecha de anteriores a la de hoy */
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("fecha")[0].setAttribute('min', today);

/*Restringo Fecha de selección hasta 180 días después de la fecha actual */
var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split('T')[0]
document.getElementsByName("fecha")[0].setAttribute('max', maxDate)




//Tenés un array de strings de fecha
var disableDates = ['31-10-2020', '01-11-2020', '25-12-2020', '01-01-2021'];
//Prefiero llevarlo a Date().getTime()
const feriados = disableDates.map(f=>new Date(+(f=f.split('-'))[2], +f[1]-1, +f[0]).getTime());


//Validación de feriados DESPUES de que el usuario seleccionó una fecha
function sinFeriados(e){
    //Obtenemos el valor de la fecha con getTime()
    let f = e.target.value.split('-'), 
        elegido = new Date(+f[0], +f[1]-1, +f[2]).getTime();

    //comprobamos contra el array de feriados
    if( feriados.includes(elegido) ){
        e.target.setCustomValidity('No se puede elegir un feriado');
    } else {
        e.target.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
function mostrarValidacion(e){
    if (!e.target.reportValidity()){ //muestra validación
        e.target.value = '';
    }
}

//Asociar evento a todos los input dates
var dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type=date]');
for (let inp of dateInputs) {
    inp.addEventListener('input',sinFeriados);
    inp.addEventListener('focusout',mostrarValidacion);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <label>
          <div>
              Seleccione Fecha
              <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" required>
          </div>
          <span class="validity"></span>
      </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Qué hicimos? Disparamos el evento `input` cuando el usuario modifica la fecha, y buscamos si esa fecha se encuentra en el array de feriados. Si se encuentra, se usa la validación personalizada y al perder el foco, se elimina el `value` del input y se muestra el error de validación con el formato que tiene por defecto el navegador.